# Cannot get QSettings to read from custom storage format

Tags: qt, sqlite, qt5, storage, qsettings

I'm trying to create a custom format for `QSettings`, but I can't get it to read from the storage.

In the code below, if I run `settings.setValue("test", 123")`, it correctly calls the write function and prints `Calling writeSqlite`. However, if I try `settings.value("test")`, it doesn't call the read function and doesn't print `Calling readSqlite`.

Any idea what could be the issue?

```
bool readSqlite(QIODevice &device, QSettings::SettingsMap &map) {
    qDebug() << "Calling readSqlite";
    return true;
}

bool writeSqlite(QIODevice &device, const QSettings::SettingsMap &map) {
    qDebug() << "Calling writeSqlite";
    return true;
}

void Settings::initialize() {
    const QSettings::Format SqliteFormat = QSettings::registerFormat("sqlite", &readSqlite, &writeSqlite);
    QSettings::setDefaultFormat(SqliteFormat);

    QSettings settings;
    // This doesn't work:
    // qDebug() << settings.value("test");

    // This works:
    // settings.setValue("test", 123456);
}
```

Comment: You have configured the QApplication. {your application}.setApplicationName(""), setOrganizationName('')

Comment: @eyllanesc, at the beginning of my application I've added `QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName(...)`, etc. and actually `QSettings` works with the default storage so I think the organization, application name and so on are set correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QSettings` does not call the custom read function (`readSqlite` in your case) unless the settings file is **readable** and **has a non-zero size** (obviously, It does not need to call it if these conditions are not met). See [source code here](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/io/qsettings.cpp?h=5.7#n1431).

Since your custom write function does not really write anything to `device`, your settings file is left empty, and `readSqlite` is not called.

If you want to see your `readSqlite` function getting called, you can add some arbitrary data to your settings file, or maybe add some [`device.write()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#write) call in your `writeSqlite` implementation, and your `readSqlite` function will get called in the next run.

Comment: Thanks, that must indeed be the reason. But then I'm wondering is it possible to get it to work with a virtual storage (not associated with a specific file) like a database or the Windows registry?

Comment: I think that this is worth asking a separate question. Anyway, at first glance, I can say that you may need to have a custom `QIODevice` that can properly encapsulate your storage medium (whether it was a database or windows registry), so that `write()`ing to that `QIODevice` will insert records/keys to the database/registry, and `read()`ing will retrieve those records/keys.

Comment: @Mike That is exactly what's needed here. A fake `QIODevice` is needed.

Comment: @KubaOber , thanks for the confirmation. Since you are here, I was thinking about how can that be implemented, and I came to the conclusion that this even requires `QSettings` to be subclassed (so that it takes a table name/registry path instead of the filename), and even the original `QSettings` constructor taking a `filename` should no longer be available. So, it seems like there is no need to use `QSettings` at all, and start from scratch, am I right? or am I thinking in a wrong way?

Comment: For now, I went for a ugly hack of writing one byte to the `QIODevice` and that indeed solves the issue. It seems that making it work properly would indeed require rewriting a good part of the class. Maybe it's possible to keep the automatic sync and thread safety (which I think are the most important feature, since the rest is just reading/writing a list of key/values).

Comment: I don't think a fake `QIODevice` would be enough since this is something that `QSettings` creates internally.

Comment: @this.lau_ , I think that a clean solution to have `QSettings` write in sqlite format requires having a fake `QIODevice` that actually does the writing/reading process, A solution other than that is kludge, and will introduce other kludges later.

Comment: Now, we need to make `QSettings` use this custom `QIODevice` instead of a normal file. I have inspected calls to [the custom read function](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qsettings.cpp.html#1467) and the [custom write function](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qsettings.cpp.html#1521) in the Qt source code. You can see that they are always called with either a `QFile` or `QSaveFile` being passed.

Comment: I would think of overriding the [function](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qsettings.cpp.html#1393) that calls our custom read/write functions, so that it calls our custom functions with our custom `QIODevice` instead of a `QFile` but this would require access to Qt private headers, and I don't think this is a good solution.

Comment: If you are aiming for thread safety, please note that an SQL database connection in Qt can only be used from the thread that created it. see [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-modules.html#threads-and-the-sql-module). So, the only solution for this would be creating and destroying connections on every call to the custom read/write functions.

Comment: I wrote a complete example about your task [here](https://gist.github.com/micjabbour/2bb5b62a239a8d70b210641e59e8655d).

Answer (score 0):

Based on Mike's answer, this is the solution I went for. Not pretty but it works:

```
bool readSqlite(QIODevice &device, QSettings::SettingsMap &map) {
    // Read the map from SQL database
    return true;
}

bool writeSqlite(QIODevice &device, const QSettings::SettingsMap &map) {
    device.write("X", 1); // HACK - required to get readSqlite to work
    // Write the map to SQL database
    return true;
}

void Settings::initialize() {
    const QSettings::Format SqliteFormat = QSettings::registerFormat("sqlite", &readSqlite, &writeSqlite);
    QSettings::setDefaultFormat(SqliteFormat);
}
```

Comment: This will result in the unused config file growing with one byte unnecessarily every time a call to `writeSqlite` is made. If you'll be using this solution, either omit the `write` call and provide a non-empty configuration file with your application (you have to use this configuration file in `QSettings`), or add the `write` call only in case the configuration file is empty (e.g. `if(device.size() == 0) device.write("X");`).

Comment: @Mike, initially I was writing only once to this device, however it seems Qt clears the device every time before calling writeSqlite (which again resulted in readSqlite not being called), so that's why I've ended writing to it every time too. The additional check on `device.size()` would indeed make sense though, just in case.

Comment: Yes, you are right. `QSettings` will always open the file in write only mode, so that the file will always be overwritten with new data from the settings map. Before writing to the device, `device.size()` will always return `0` in the custom write function. Sorry, I missed that point while writing my first comment.